# I cannot play music in the status "uploaded" in iTunes through iCloud (via Apple TV, iPhone, iPad)

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

I have a subscription to iTunes Match.

Recently, I think in the last week, I am not able to listen to the music that result in the status "Uploaded" , therefore is not matched.

Normally if I load a cd in my iTunes library (on my Mac) it sync with iCloud and I could have 2 status: Upload or Matched.

In the recent past I could play any song in either the two status with any device with the same Apple ID associated.

Now (in the last week) I cannot play anymore the pieces with the iCloud status "uploaded".

Is there anybody who had the same experience and who have solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently - I could see the songs in my library on my iPhone, but I couldn't play them. In iTunes, the iCloud status of the files was Uploaded.

What fixed it for me was plugging my iPhone into the computer with my iTunes library, and syncing. It didn't seem to transfer any files (other than doing a backup), but after that, I could play all of my songs on my phone.

This might help for your iPad and iPhone, but unfortunately, probably not the Apple TV.